# Regular expression to match n digit before precision and only two digit after precision

Tags: regex

Eg: only allow
< n digit>.<2 digit>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0-9]{0,}\.[0-9]{2}` if you need exactly 2 digit after the dot

`[0-9]{0,}(\.[0-9]{1,2}){0,1}` if precision can be empty